# Adding object in array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an `Array` object in my code:

```
cities =[{city_name:'NY',X:'1',Y:'2'}]
```

I'm trying to get new city info using ajax and add to `cities` array.
I get the response from ajax and make exact object like above, but when I try to push new object into array nothing happen.

My full code:

```html
<script>
  cities = [{
      svgPath: targetSVG,
      title: "Romania",
      latitude: 44.4333000183,
      longitude: 26.1000003815,
    }

    , {
      svgPath: targetSVG,
      title: "China",
      latitude: 39.8897018433,
      longitude: 115.275001526,
    }

    , {
      svgPath: targetSVG,
      title: "Taiwan",
      latitude: 24.8047008514,
      longitude: 120.9713974,
    }
  ];

  function push_test() {
    temp = {
      arc: -0.85,
      alpha: 0.9,
      latitudes: 1,
      longitudes: 2
    };
    cities.push(temp);
  }
</script>

<button onclick='push_test()'>test</button>
```

Comment: any errors on the console

Comment: that's the problem .. no error in console .sadly

Comment: Can you post full code.

Comment: Please try to `console.log(cities);` after variable initialization and also after `cities.push` method and paste log here.

Comment: thanks kcp for edit

Comment: "*nothing happen*" is not helpful. Describe what you expect to happen. Your code does not produce any output, so nothing visible will happen. PS you should declare variables, but not declaring them won't affect the outcome here.

Comment: i meant when i check my source code at the moment i don't see any change in cities array . i m try console.log(cities)  i get same result, cities values don't change

Comment: There is a syntax error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: targetSVG`. There are also trailing commas after the last member of each object, which are syntax errors in some browsers. Fix the errors and it "works".

Comment: Other than the error `targetSVG is not defined`, everything works just fine.

Comment: The code does what suppose to do, maybe the error is in other piece of your code.

Comment: thanks a lot . my problem fixed .